# How to catch the model sent with the partial view from the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a partial view that returns my partial view needed, but i need to catch the model because the json.encode gets the primary model sent with main view because there was no submit done to the form.

I need to model sent with the partialview so i can use it instead of json.encode

```
   public ActionResult addField(List<Destination> model)
    {
        model.Add(new Destination
        {
            path = String.Empty,
        });

        return PartialView("_ChampDestination",model);
    }
```

and here is the ajax call

```
  function addField(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.RepertoireDestinationMultiple));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '@Url.Action("addField", "Flux")',

            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                var x = response.model;
                $(".destinationMultiple").html(response);
            }
            , error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(error);}
        });

    }
```

The new i add with the action is not registred in the main model.

Comment: Is the problem reading the form and passing that to the action? everything else seems to be OK from what I can tell.  Maybe include some sample `HTML` and `JSON` for clarity?

Comment: the partialview is rendered well, what i want is to catch the model sent with it so i can use it if i want to add other fields, cause after the first adding ill have a model sent to the view with 2 fields, i want to use that one

Comment: you have it captured in `var model`, what I tend to do is store that `json` in a hidden field or the `data` property a field so I can read/modify it later.  Is that the kind of thing that you are after?

Comment: yes i want to populate that variable with the data used to create the partialview @Steve0

Comment: the var model bytheway contains nothing, was just trying out if it works. @Steve0

Comment: Your comment on my answer indicates that you are modifying/setting the destination  array server-side.  If that is the case then code for `_ChampDestination` would be helpful.  If you write the variable to a form element there than you can read it the next time you need to send it to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a common method that I use to modify a list like this and then submit back to the server.

Note that I do not actually call your ajax function in this snippet as you indicated it works fine.  This answer shows how someone might manipulate the contents of a field for later submission.

```js
//changed your function to simply submit data
function submitData(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("addField", "Flux")',

    data: $("input#destinations").val(),
    success: function(response) {
      debugger;
      var x = response.model;
      $(".destinationMultiple").html(response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

}

function addDestination(dest) {
  var data = $.parseJSON($("input#destinations").val() || "[]");
  var obj = {
    path: dest
  }
  data.push(obj);
  $("input#destinations").val(JSON.stringify(data));
  $("#output").text($("input#destinations").val());
}

$("#add").click(function(e) {
  addDestination($("#addIt").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id='destinations' type='hidden' value='' /> <!-- original list in JSON goes in the value here -->
<input id='addIt' type='text' value='YOW' />
<button id='add'>ADD</button>
<div id='output'></div>
```

If, as indicated in your comment to this answer, this needs to be modified server-side `input#destinations` needs to be filled out server-side than simply include that input in the `partial-view` and read it from there and ignore the code that modifies it client-side.

Comment: But my modifcation has been done server side and pushed to clientside with the ajax call, cant it be done that way? cause i feel you are doing the modification client side and saving it